# Buildroot fails can't find a python module : "ImportError : Cython not found !"

Tags: python, cython, buildroot

I'm trying to run a full `make` on Buildroot. I added some Python packages as hdbscan. Unfortunately, it seems Buildroot needs Cython to build hbdscan and can't find it, even though it seems to be installed...

here is the error I get after running `make` :

```
<path to buildroot>/output/build/python-hdbscan-0.8.27/setup.py:8: UserWarning : No module named 'Cython'
warnings.warn(e.args[0])
<path to buildroot>/output/build/python-hdbscan-0.8.27/setup.py:92: UserWarning : Due to incompatibilities with Python 3.7 hdbscan nowrequires Cython to be installed in order to built it
warnings.warn("Due to incompatibilities with Python 3.7 hdbscan now")
...
raise ImportError('Cython not fuond ! Please install cython and try again')
ImportError: Cython not fuond ! Please install cython and try again
```

The `setup.py` file it's trying to run does ask to `import cython` but it's supposed to be installed already. I tried every command I could see on the forums but nothing will do... As I have several versions of Python installed on my virtual machine, I thought it could be the cause of the problem but I'm not sure about that anymore... I runned a few commands like those :

- `sudo pip install cython`
- `sudo apt --reinstall install cython`
- `sudo python3.7 -m pip install cython`
- `sudo apt-get install cython`
  some commands to upgrade cython, pip...
  some commands to uninstall cython then install it again...

I don't know what to try anymore... Does anyone has an idea what I could do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need cython to be part of the cross-compilation environment, not simply installed on your build machine. Any `pip` or `apt` you run on your build machine are not going to help.

In Buildroot, it's trivially easy to do this: add a dependency on Cython in the `python-hdbscan.mk` file:

```
PYTHON_HDBSCAN_DEPENDENCIES += python-cython
```

For completeness, you also need the corresponding dependency in `Config.in`:

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON_HDBSCAN
        ...
        select BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON_CYTHON
        ...
```